# ext.data.record conditional validation

Tags: extjs

I am working w/ Ext 3.3
How can I do conditional value checking, on the Ext.data package level, like; 
if the person is married, require spouse name, otherwise let it be blank.

The solution I am looking for should be on the data package. (lets say that I dont have much control about how data is edited, but I am responsible for validating it.)
Ext.Data.Field lets me say allowBlank, true or false. I wonder if I can pass a function there which accepts the record, and returns true or false based on the other fields on the record.

I am looking for an alternative solutions for this, on the Ext.data package, (on the Store or Record level).

Comment: just listen to the appropriate 'before' event on the store (before insert, update), perform your validation and return true/false to  accept/reject the modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on when you are doing the validation.

If you are validating when `store.load();` is invoked, then I suggest the following:

```
    myStore.on('beforeload', function(store, loadOptions) {
        var isValid = true;
        var modifiedRecs = store.getModifiedRecords();
        Ext.each(modifiedRecs, (function(record, index, modifiedArray) {
            // do validation here
            // if validation failed, use the following two lines of code:
            // isValid = false;
            // return false;   // this exits modifiedRecs.each
        }, this);
        return isValid;  // If falsey, this return statement cancels loading.
                         // Note: the 'loadexception' event will be now be fired
                         // by myStore if isValid is falsey.
    });
```

If you are validating whenever data changes in the store, then use the following:

```
    myStore.on('beforesave', function(store, data) {
        // simply do validation against `data`.
        // data will contain an array of records for each type of action that
        // was being saved, e.g., data['update'] === [updatedRec1, ...].
        // if validation failed, just `return false` to cancel saving.
    });
```

Here's what it means to be [falsey](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript).